# Should I compile coffeescript files to js before using in production?

Tags: node.js, deployment, coffeescript

When deploying coffeescript code, is there any benefit to using `coffee --compile`, compiling it to js and then running with `node`, instead of using `coffee` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods otherwise both compile into JavaScript files, unless you specify the `--nodes` flag, which parses the CoffeeScript rather than compiling it. In a production environment, you might not want the overhead of parsing and writing compiled JavaScript, but the difference isn't large.

It's up to you whether you want to compile before running on a production environment, but if you do, then the probability of getting errors could be lower.

The compile and write process source is [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/lib/coffee-script/command.js).

Comment: I just require without extension all the time, so never had to use `require('coffee-script')`.

Comment: So you compile all your scripts individually? The only main difference is that you don't need to compile the CoffeeScript when starting the application if you run with Node and don't have the overhead of compiling and writing compiled JavaScript to disk.

Comment: No, I meant that I write `require('./stuff')` instead of `require('./stuff.js')` or `require('./stuff.coffee)`, so it works with both `node` and `coffee`. I suppose you meant that I could require uncompiled coffee from js, so just ignore that comment)